# How to split lines from Windows text file (/r/n separation)

Tags: c#, .net, string

My question is quite simple. I need to get all text lines from Windows text file.
All lines are separated by \r\n symbols. I use String.Split, but its not cool, because
it only splits 'by one symbol' leaving empty string that I need to remove with options flag. Is there a better way?

My implementation

```
string wholefile = GetFromSomeWhere();

// now parsing
string[] lines = operationtext.Split("\r\n".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// ok now I have lines array
```

**UPDATE**

File.ReadAllXXX is of no use here coz GetFromSomeWhere is actually RegEx, so I've no file after this point.

Comment: definitely check out this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost there, just needs a little more support :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) of `String.Split`, which takes an array of strings that can serve as delimiters:

```
string[] lines = operationtext.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine },  
                                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Of course, if you already have the file-path, it's much simpler to use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx):

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
```

Comment: Cannot use, but what if I see in Reflector what it does

Comment: @Captain Comic: To answer your question, on .NET 3.5, I can see that `File.ReadAllLines` uses a `StreamReader` to read the file line by line, loading each line into an `ArrayList`. It then turns this into a string-array with the `ArrayList.ToArray` method.

Comment: @Captain Comic: You say "cannot use" without explaining why. I don't understand why either one or both of these two methods won't do exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Cody, I have no filepath. The regex loads the file parses it and returns me some parts from the original file. If there were String.ReadAllLines(string).

Answer (score 4):

String.Split does accept a string (like "\r\n"). Not just a chararray.

```
string[] lines = wholetext.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 4):

You may find it much easier to simply use [File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or [File.ReadLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

you could use an extension method like the one below and your code would then look like this:

```
    var lines = operationText.ReadAsLines();
```

Extension method implementation:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadAsLines(this string text)
    {
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(text);
        while(reader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            yield return reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I'm guessing it's not as performant as the split option which is usually very performant but if that's not an issue...